# obj is undefined sometimes and works perfectly other times

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the computed propertys I am trying to match an ID received from an API to an array of objects with ID keys also received from an API and retrieve the name key from the matching ID object.

the obj variable occasionally throws an "obj is undefined" error but not consistently.

I think its to do with the IDs been async. Changed the function from arrow to classic function to not mess with the this scope.

```
  data() {
    return {
      upComing: [],
      popular: [],
      topRated: [],
      playingNow: [],
      details: [],
      genres: []
    }
  },

  computed: {
    genre: function() {
      let list = this.upComing[0] ? this.upComing[0].genre_ids[0] : 0
      let obj = this.genres.find(function(o) {
        return o.id === list
      })
      return obj.name
    }
  },

  created() {
    let self = this
    APIService.getUpcoming()
      .then(response => {
        self.upComing = response.data.results
        //console.log(this.upComing)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`There was an error: ${error.response}`)
      }),
      APIService.getGenres()
        .then(response => {
          this.genres = response.data.genres
          //console.log(this.genres)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(`There was an error: ${error.response}`)
        })
  }
}
```

I get this `TypeError: "obj is undefined"` and this `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: obj is undefined"`

and it throws them each twice. So i have 4 errors in the console but its just these 2 twice with a 1 second delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely right about the issue being the async stuff, couldn't you just safeguard against `undefined` by doing something like this:

```js
  computed: {
    genre: function() {
      let list = this.upComing[0] ? this.upComing[0].genre_ids[0] : 0
      let obj = this.genres.find(function(o) {
        return o.id === list
      })
      return obj ? obj.name : '' // or whatever should be the default
    }
  },
```

Comment: Despite using ternarys already how did I not think about doing that. Perfect fix! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `this.genres` is `[]`, so the computed property is computed when your component is mounted, so the result of `this.genres.find(....` is undefined (because it can't find something in an empty list).

You can have a default value by using the `||` notation like this:

```
let obj = this.genres.find(function(o) {
        return o.id === list
      }) || { name: 'defaultName'}
```

This means that if nothing is found on the genres list, you still have a default result, then you can return `obj.name` with out having the error.

Also note that the `genres` variable is empty because the computed method is tun before your promise is resolved, and it runs again after you update that variable